# Unable to flash latest factory images to a refurb Nexus 5

Tags: nexus-5, factory-image

I purchased a Nexus 5 from [Taobao](https://item.taobao.com/item.htm?spm=a1z09.2.0.0.se9bkA&id=42466107098&_u=j1jhvqlde9e) for a bargain price of around $177. I assume it's some kind of refurb. I've tried flashing with the latest Android 5 Developer Preview as well as the latest stable release 5.1.1 (LMY48M). Both get stuck at `sending 'system'` when flashed with `flash-all`. I contacted the seller and was told to use [Shuame](http://www.shuame.com/) software for Windows. Using that software I was able to flash a modified Android 4.4.4 ROM.

I don't want to be stuck with such an old, non-stock ROM but so far it's the only thing that works. Is it possible that I got some fake hardware that makes the newer releases incompatible? How should I go about testing if this Nexus 5 is real?

Update: Here's the specs from About phone:

[image: System details]
<sup>System details (click to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: I've never heard of that software before. I would guess you've bought a fake Nexus 5 although I can't be sure. Can you post a screenshot of the `Settings` > `About phone` screen showing build number, kernel version etc?

Comment: I just noticed that `lsusb` reports the device ID as `18d1:4ee2 Google Inc. Nexus 4 (debug)`.

Comment: I never had a Nexus, but `lsusb` reporting a device as "Nexus 4" seems a strong indicator it's not a Nexus 5. I've seen several devices posing as "Nexus" (for "driver ease" I guess), none of them being a "brand name"; so I'd say this is a strong indicator for a fake. Another one is that you have to use some never-heard-of software for flashing as nothing else works *with a Nexus device* – pretty unlikely a real Nexus would require that.

Comment: The screenshot cut it off but it only reports 779 MB of memory leading me to believe it's a fake.

Comment: Does the flash work manually? Please check the device code when you use ADB devices command and post it.

Comment: The device code is 0489fd8a145044d6. Flashing works for the radio, recovery and bootloader images but fails on the system image.